# The difference between the flabby sheaf and the fine sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory

As we know,the flabby sheaf and the fine sheaf are all acyclic,but does one imply another?I need some examples to distinguish them,who can help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sheaf of $C^{\infty}$ functions on paracompact manifold $X$ is fine because exists partitions of unity on $X$. But is not flabby because you cannot extend function on open subset $U$ if function blow up at frontier of $U$.
Constant sheaf with values in  $\mathbb Z$ is flabby on irreducible algebraic variety  but not fine.